# Disable asynchronous checkout in Team Foundation Server workspace

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have a problem with the Source Control settings of one of my project collections on the Team Foundation Server.

I need multiple file checkouts not possible. I know where the configuration is and what I have to change:

1-The work area of each team to establish it on the server

2-change the configuration of the team project collection to uncheck the "Enable asynchronous checkout of server workspaces" box.

3-The configuration of each project in the collection to disable multiple check-out.

To be able to do step 3 I need step 2, and this is where I have the problem, even if I put everything correctly.

At the moment of OK it seems that everything has gone well but if I go back into the screen everything continues as it was until now and nothing has changed.

I have other collections of projects where I have been able to configure this correctly, something must be escaping me and I cannot find the solution

I am using the VS2019 and the 2013 version of the Team Foundation Server

Thanks for helping, regards!

Answer (score 0):

You could check whether the workspace you are using is a **Local** Workspace or **Server** Workspace:

[image]

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/decide-between-using-local-server-workspace?view=azure-devops

If you use Server workspace, please add some screenshots in your original post to describe your issue.

Comment: How's your issue going?